# How to Bulk-Crop many images whitespace?

Tags: photo-editing, cropping

I want to crop the white space in 300 pictures

Is there any software out there that does it?

Comment: [Irfanview ](http://www.irfanview.com) 
Free. Marvellous

Comment: Assuming the whitespace is all the same area of the photos - yes, this is easy to automate using the methods below. However, if the whitespace moves around the frame in all 300, then you'll need more sophisticated software to detect and crop out the blank area.

Answer (score 6):

There are enough programs, even free, which do what you want. Usually, these are picture managers which allow you to select the files/directories to process and what processing/conversion to do for them.

For example the procedure for the [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html) (freeware) is as following:

- select the desired files directories.
- go to `Tools > Batch Processing...`
- on the first tab of the `Batch Processing` window (the 'General' tab) set the destination directory (if you don't want to have your files overwritten) and the output format if you want to change it.
- on the second tab (the `Transformations` tab) select from the List of Available Transformations the `Auto Crop` feature and click `Add` to add it to the list of the active transformations on the left. On the `Parameters` panel at bottom you will choose your desired color (white). Alternatively, if your images must be cropped at exactly same size and offset there is another option (transformation) which will work, perhaps, better.
- press the `Go` button and check at the end your destination folder if everything went ok.

The entire process is much simpler than it sounds.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for when I found this thread, and very easy to use, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Irfanview.
Press B to go to Batch conversion, add your images, click "advanced" and tick "Auto crop borders".
Works a treat.